# Android Export Wizard fails creating signed apk cause of duplicate entry .ds_store when Proguard is enabled on Mac OS X

Tags: android, macos, apk, proguard

The Android export wizard throws a ZipException caused by duplicate entry .DS_STORE.
Is there a way to tell Proguard and/or the Android Export Wizard to ignore the .DS_STORE files and solve this problem?

This is the detailed long story:

I wanted to enable Proguard for my Android project. I uncommented the following line from the project.properties of the Android project

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Now when I try to export a signed apk the from Eclipse (right click on the project -> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package) the Export Wizard fails returning Failed to export application.

From the Error Log view of Eclipse it does appear an error. By double clicking on it this is the stacktrace:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Failed to export application
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:318)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.doExport(ExportWizard.java:296)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.access$0(ExportWizard.java:233)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard$1.run(ExportWizard.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: .DS_Store
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.putNextEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:215)
    at java.util.jar.JarOutputStream.putNextEntry(JarOutputStream.java:109)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.addFileToJar(ExportHelper.java:407)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.addFileToJar(ExportHelper.java:394)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:242)
    ... 4 more
```

so it looks like a ZipException is throwed because there are multiple .DS_STORE files (which are hidden system files of MAC OS X).

Answer (score 0):

With Ant, you could add [file filters](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#filefilters) to the `-injars` options of the `proguard` task in `<android-sdk>/tools/ant/build.xml`. For instance:

```
-injars ${project.all.classes.value}(!**.DS_STORE)
```

This tells ProGuard to ignore any .DS_STORE files when reading the input.

With Eclipse, the configuration is hard-coded, so that's not possible.

Other developers on MacOS X may know more...

Answer (score 0):

A workaround:

- recursively remove all .DS_Store in Terminal.
  See this link https://jonbellah.com/recursively-remove-ds-store/
- export the project in Eclipse